# cv2.VideoWriter() Doesn't work on the Raspberry Pi with the Raspicam

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture

I use the following code to capture motion on the Raspicam, the issue is that cv2.VideoWriter() doesn't seem to work on the Pi, I have read about this issue and I have installed the v4l driver yet it still doesn't appear to work.

If anyone has an alternative method for capturing video or a solution for this one he would be of immense help to me.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

MOTION_RECORD_TIME = timedelta(seconds = 3)


def have_motion(frame1, frame2):
    if frame1 is None or frame2 is None:
        return False
    delta = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(delta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    return numpy.sum(thresh) > 0

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)

prev_frame = None
last_motion = None
motion_filename = None
motion_file = None

frame_size = camera.resolution
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*"XVID")

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array



    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame_gray, (21, 21), 0)



    if have_motion(prev_frame, frame_gray):
        if motion_file is None:
            now = datetime.now()
            motion_filename = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_MOTION.h264")
            motion_file = cv2.VideoWriter(motion_filename, fourcc, 20.0, frame_size)
            last_motion = time.time()
        print "Motion!", last_motion

    if motion_file is not None:
        motion_file.write(image)
        print 'Saving...'
        print now
        print time.time() - last_motion
        if time.time() - last_motion > 3:
            motion_file.release()
            motion_file = None
            print 'Saved'
            print motion_filename
            break


    prev_frame = frame_gray
    cv2.imshow('frame', image)
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

Comment: Have you tried diffrent codecs and file endings? For me it worked to write my application in cpp.

Comment: @al-eax what codec worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the codec from

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*"XVID")
```

to

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*"MPV4")
```

and by changing

```
motion_filename = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_MOTION.h264")
```

to

```
motion_filename = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_MOTION.avi")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OpenCV 4.5.1 on an Raspberry Pi 3 and this worked for my use-case:

```
filename = f"recording_{time.time()}.mp4"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, FPS, RES)
```